# What does a 2012 Mac Mini need for microphone input?

Tags: mac, audio, microphone

I need a simply jack Mic unamplified physically connected to my Mac Mini (late 2012 model) through Audio-IN and it doesn't work.

I also tried the original iPhone's headphones to no avail and I wonder if this is normal?

[image]

Does the Mac Mini require a USB microphone or can I use the [Audio Line-in port](http://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs.html) with another type of microphone?

UPDATE 10/14: I tried using a 3 channel splitter like this

[image]

then I plugged my speakers and my earphones with mic but nothing to do, mic still doesn't work... (maybe just because this splitter has a 3 channel male jack but it's a normal 2 ch; I bought it for 2€ from China so it's possible..)

Comment: Is your simple jack mic expecting phantom power or an amplifier? Which Mac Mini do you have since the hardware has changed significantly since it was introduced in 2005.

Comment: Mac Mini late 2012 and simply jack Mic unamplified

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The audio-in port on Mac Minis is a [line-level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) port, meaning that a standard PC microphone may not be audible without some sort of amplifier.

On any Mini from [2010 and later](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP585), you can use the Apple headset (the kind that comes with the iPhone), but you have to plug it into the *headphone* port, not the audio-in port. There are [also adapters available](http://www.headsetbuddy.com/pc-computer-headset-to-3-5mm-smartphone-adapter/) that allow you to use any standard PC headset with that port.

On older Minis, you'll have to use a USB audio adapter. The [iMic](https://griffintechnology.com/products/audio/imic-usb-audio-adapter) is a popular one, but there are many others out there.

Comment: aaahhhhh so headphone port is pre amplified and Audio-IN port no, right?  So something like this would be a solution? http://www.happydgroup.com/ebay/Cost/1095wht.jpg (to speakers and mic)

Comment: Can't tell for sure from that link (it's just a picture), but it appears like that would do the right thing. It does have the proper TRRS connector. If that answers your question, please mark it as answered (green checkmark).

Comment: I purchased one of those adapters, it works with my iPhone but not with my 2011 iMac. iPhone earbuds do work with my iMac.

Answer (score 0):

My Mini is mid-2011.
In System Preferences->Sound if offers:
Output:
- Internal Speakers
Input:
- Line-in

I tried to use a simple Logitech headset (which I use on my PC) with [the adapter](http://www.headsetbuddy.com/pc-computer-headset-to-3-5mm-smartphone-adapter/), but it didn't work - simply nothing happens when I plug it in, Preferences stay the same, and no sound is heard.

Today I tried different [headset](http://images.fonearena.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/LG-QuadBeat-3.jpg), the one that came with LG G4 smartphone. And it works. As soon as I plug it in, the System Preferences->Sound changes.

System Preferences->Sound now shows:
Output:
- Headphones
Input:
- External Microphone
- Line-in

When I select External Microphone, it records nicely.

So, it depends very much on the headset.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue with my late 2012 mac mini today, found the adaptor that i discarded for my pc gaming headset and plugged it into the line out socket, now works perfectly in Skype, teamspeak etc

Comment: So you connected two jacks (one for output, like speakers, and one for input, like a microphone) and they all works fine (you can play music in speakers and record from microphone)?

Answer (score -3):

Get a USB Stereo Sound adapter  $8 problem solved